# Laravel: return multiple relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following table:

[image]

The table is called `user_eggs` and it stores the user eggs.
eggs are items with additional data (`hatch_time`)

As you can see, user 2 has 2 eggs, which are items 46 and 47.

My `items` table stores the item general information such as name, image, description, etc...

How I can return the user eggs using `$user->eggs()` including the item data in my `items` table of the egg `item_id`?

I tried:

User Model:

```
/**
     * Get the eggs
     */
    public function eggs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Egg::Class, 'user_eggs','user_id','item_id')
        ->withPivot('id','hatch_time');
    }
```

but `$user->eggs()` returns an empty array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the hatch_time when looping through the records or do you want to run queries on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach will be:
in your **UserEgg** model define:

```
    /**
     * Get the user associated with egg.
     */
    public function _user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
    /**
     * Get the item associated with egg.
     */
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item','item_id');
    }
```

then in your controller:

use the model to extract everything like this:

```
$userEggs = UserEgg::where('user_id',2)->get();
foreach($userEggs as $userEgg){
    $associateduser = $userEgg->_user;
    $associatedItem = $userEgg->item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

If you loop through the user's eggs:

```
foreach($user->eggs as $egg){
    $item = Item::find($egg->pivot->item_id);
}
```

If you want to query:

```
$user->eggs()->wherePivot('item_id', 1)->get();
```

## Long answer

[From the Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

**Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns**

As you have already learned, working with many-to-many relations requires the presence of an intermediate table. Eloquent provides some very helpful ways of interacting with this table. For example, let's assume our User object has many Role objects that it is related to. After accessing this relationship, we may access the intermediate table using the pivot attribute on the models:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

Notice that each Role model we retrieve is automatically assigned a pivot attribute. This attribute contains a model representing the intermediate table, and may be used like any other Eloquent model.

By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

If you want your pivot table to have automatically maintained created_at and updated_at timestamps, use the withTimestamps method on the relationship definition:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
```

**Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns**

You can also filter the results returned by belongsToMany using the wherePivot and wherePivotIn methods when defining the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivot('approved', 1);

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivotIn('priority', [1, 2]);
```

Comment: As I said user->eggs reutrn an empty array, so I can't foreach, there is a problem I have no idea what

Comment: Are you using the correct user? And if you dump (`dd()`) the result of `$user->eggs()` what do you get? If you get an instance of Builder, you should use `$user->eggs` without the parentheses.